# How to get value of an input if checkbox in that row is clicked in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I have it so that it will show a row with mysql and at the end I have an input to put in a date and then insert it into the database. I cannot figure out how to make it so that it updates each input individually with each checked box row.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo  "<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-10 col-offset-1'>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chk1[$i]' value='".$row['customerid']."' /> " .$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']. 
    "</td>
    <td>"  .
    $row['phonenumber'].
    "</td> 
    <td>" .$row['brand'].
    "</td>
    <td>" .$row['stock'].
    "</td>
    <td>" .$row['shoename'].
    "</td>
    <td>" .$row['size'].$row['width']. "</td>"; 
    echo "<td><input name='backorder' type='date'/></td>
    <td id='comments'>" .$row['comment']. "</td> 
    </div>
    </div>";
$cid[$i] = $row['customerid'];
$i++;
}
```

So when I update with this below it updates everything fine but gives all rows in the database the same value for the backorder.

```
if(isset($_POST['chk1'])) {
    foreach($_POST['chk1'] as $cid[$i]) {
        $chk1[] = array($cid[$i]);
        if(!empty($chk1)) {

            //include("email.php");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE customerid =" .$cid[$i];
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $texting = $row['texting'];
                    $name = $row['firstname'];
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    $provider = $row['provider'];
                    $brand = $row['brand'];
                    //$sql must be in this loop in order to execute all checkboxes.

                    $sql = "UPDATE shoes SET ordered=CURDATE(), backorder='backorder' WHERE customerid=".$cid[$i];
```

Comment: I think you might need ajax to get whether or not the input is checked and compare the checkbox id with a value from ajax, then only update checked values not 100% so didn't put in answer

Comment: you'd either need a per-row form, so every row has its own submit button, or you use javascript and ajax to extract values from that row and send ONLY those values to the server, not the rest of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL sends a static string value for the update of that field.

`$sql = "UPDATE shoes SET ordered=CURDATE(), backorder='backorder' WHERE customerid=".$cid[$i];` Needs to be updated to use something variable for the value or the string "backorder" will become the value for anything updated.

Comment: Right, I've had it put to backorder[] and backorder[$i]. Do you think there is another way that will make this possible? I was going to do a foreach before the formsubmission but the process seems I'd be trying to pull from empty variables.